# php://input пустой, при content-type: application/json

Tags: php

Собственно вопрос в сабже, поток пустой при отправке json.
Посылаю тоже самое но с заголовком application/x-www-form-urlencoded и данные содержатся в потоке. Почему он не содержит данные, при джсон заголовке?

Comment: Может `application/json`?

Comment: да, исправил. но в коде написано верно

Comment: Отправляю без заголовка - все ок.

Comment: Давайте код посмотрим ?